# Mirth license key under docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mirth

I am using mirth 4.2.0 and mirth connect server is running docker container. I want to add license key for my mirth.
I want to add license key for mirth 4.2.0 that is running in docker container

As I take guide it says we have to add license.key variable in mirth.properties file
My question is how can I add my license key for mirth that is running in docker container?
I am running by using docker-compose file and tried to add environment variable for license key but didn't succeed.
I have also tried by binding custom mirth properties file with volumes of docker but it didn't get that properties file.